# How to generate unique random sequence of four numbers in java

Tags: java, random, numbers, set, sequence

i've been trying to figure out how to write the code in Java that would generate unique number sequences as follows:**

> 0012 3929 2003 2201 3994 etc...
>
> 55562 23369 66665 77742 15489 etc...
>
> 556612 211135 222566 333365 etc...

with all possible numbers in sequence of four or five or more number blocks...

Comment: *...sequence of four numbers...* All your example sequences have more than 4 numbers.

Comment: please add more description to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse out your question here: Given input '4', you want to generate every possible number between 0000 and 9999 (so, 10000 numbers), in random order?

One option is to first create ALL the numbers in a collection, then, shuffle it:

```
var list = IntStream.of(0, 10000)
  .mapToObj(n -> String.format("%04d", n))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Or if the 'lowest' number is 1000, well, change that 0 to a 1000, works just as well.

You can do this for any input, but once you get to around 8, it starts becoming unwieldy; that takes a lot of memory.

There are ways to do this, but it gets quite complicated; presumably the above is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to see the sequence as an String as it is possible it will not fit in an int or long.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(randomNumbersInNBlocks(4,4));
    System.out.println(randomNumbersInNBlocks(4,6));
    System.out.println(randomNumbersInNBlocks(6,4));
    System.out.println(randomNumbersInNBlocks(6,6));
}

private static String randomNumbersInNBlocks(int numbersInBlock, int blockCount){
    final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++) {
        String numbers;
        do{
            numbers = getRandomNumbers(numbersInBlock);
        }while (builder.toString().contains(numbers));
        builder.append(numbers);
        builder.append(" ");
    }

    return builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() -1).toString();
}

private static String getRandomNumbers(int numberCount){
    final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (numberCount-- != 0) {
        int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Would it produce all 10000 numbers for the sequence of 4 numbers? If i run it like this: 
   System.out.println(randomNumbersInNBlocks(4,10000));

Comment: Another questions is, how can i implement randomNumbersInNBlocks(a,b) method into for loop so that it loads all possible values(b) into Array or produce blocks(b) one by one instead of bulk

Comment: @AndriusMickevičius The getRandomNumbers(int numberCount) generates one block of size numberCount.